# WIll this nette routing rule potentially redirect all url requests to homepage?

Tags: routes, nette

I am in argument as junior with a senior dev that says my routing is wrong and dangerous, that potentially all request could be routed to homepege, but I think he is wrong and I even tested it. He says that by adding this

```
$this->router[] = new Route('/', 'Front:Bridge:default');
```

All routes below this definition will be ignored and everything will be routed to Front:Bridge

Which I think is BS, since the route clearly states that redirect ONLY request directly to web root to Front:Bridge. And functionality of app is indeed not changed, but he insists I am sure to introduce unforseen bug somewhere.

Whole routerFactory for ref

```
public function getRouter()
{
    $this->router[] = new Route('/muj-ucet[/<action=default>]', [
        'module' => 'Front',
        'presenter' => 'Account',
        'action' => [
            Route::VALUE => 'default',
            Route::FILTER_TABLE => [
                'zpravy' => 'message',
                'profil' => 'profile',
                'objednavky' => 'orders',
                'sprava-uzivatelu' => 'users'
            ],
        ],
    ]);
    $this->router[] = new Route('/', 'Front:Bridge:default');
    $this->router[] = new Route('[<lang [a-zA-Z]{2}>/]html/prihlaseni.html', 'OnlineUser:Front:Login:default');
    $this->router[] = new Route('/superadmin/prihlaseni', 'OnlineUser:Front:Login:superAdminLogin');
    $this->router[] = new Route('[<lang [a-zA-Z]{2}>/]html/registrace.html', 'OnlineUser:Front:Registration:default');
    $this->router[] = new Route('/potvrzeni-registrace', Linker::ACTION_CONFIRM_REGISTRATION);
    $this->router[] = new Route('/aktivace-uctu', Linker::ACTION_ACTIVATION_ACCOUNT);
    $this->router[] = new Route('/nove-heslo', Linker::ACTION_FORGOT_PASSWORD);
    $this->router[] = new Route('/logout', 'OnlineUser:Front:Login:logout');
    $this->router[] = new Route('/validace/<action=default>', [
        'module' => 'OnlineUser:Front',
        'presenter' => 'Validation',
        'action' => [
            Route::VALUE => 'default',
            Route::FILTER_TABLE => [
                'validace-emailu' => 'validateEmailNotExists',
                'validace-ico' => 'validateIcNotExists',
                'validace-ico-ares-heo' => 'validateIcAresAndHeO',
            ],
        ],
    ]);
    $this->router[] = new Route('[<path .+>]', 'Front:Bridge:default');
    return $this->router;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to settle this debate is to pull citation from the official [Nette docs](https://doc.nette.org/en/2.4/routing).

Before we answer your question, it's important to [remember the order of routes matter](https://doc.nette.org/en/2.4/routing#toc-router-factory):

> Order of routes is important, because they are tried sequentially from the first one to the last one. Basic rule is we **declare routes from the most specific to the most general.**

Next, recall that routing is matched *exactly*. If there's a route for `/foo` it will not match on a request for `/foo/bar`. There's not an official citation for this, but it's implied and easily verified with a test app.

With that knowledge, let's walk through your proposal. if you use this route:

```
$this->router[] = new Route('/', 'Front:Bridge:default');
```

You're correct. That will only match `/`. Not `/foo`, not `/foo/bar`, etc. Since it is so unambiguous, the order doesn't matter and there's not much room for disaster.

However there's an important route being made towards the end of your snippet:

```
$this->router[] = new Route('[<path .+>]', 'Front:Bridge:default');
```

This is a catch-all route that *is* different than matching `/` and is probably what your peer is actually worried about: Since it is ambiguous (by matching all paths!) the order of this route *definitely does* matter. By placing it first, all requests would redirect to `Front:Bridge:default`.